# Mysql Triggers Insert and Delete in one?

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers

I need to create an insert and delete trigger, both will do the same thing.
Can I create this in one trigger?
Or do I need two separate ones?
I've had a look around and all seem to have one for delete and another for insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySql does not allow for multiple events on the same trigger.

One option is to put your code in a procedure, and have each trigger call the same procedure - pass as much info of the old/new row to the proc as required.