# mysql trigger query excecution not ending

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to add values into a table when there is an insertion or update in 'tbl_purchase_log' table. so I create a trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
TRIGGER `purchase_log_trigger` AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
ON `tbl_purchase_log`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    INSERT INTO tbl_purchase_log_status (tbl_purchase_log_id, status, created_date) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.status, now());
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

My problem is that this query excecution not ending. Is anything wrong in this query?

Comment: wt do u mean by query execution is not ending ? plz explain

Comment: not producing a success message. it will stop after maximum excecution time limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you cannot have multiple events in a single trigger you have to have separate triggers for different events. In your case the INSERT and the UPDATE..check this links

[Mysql Triggers Insert and Delete in one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827563/mysql-triggers-insert-and-delete-in-one)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html